# how to export with repo command?

Tags: export, repository

What's the [`repo`](http://source.android.com/source/using-repo.html) equivalent of `git archive` and `svn export`? I'm working with the Android source.

Answer (score 0):

"Repo is a tool that makes it easier to work with Git in the context of Android" tells ["Downloading the Source Tree" page](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html) on top.

Thus - download source (*I suppose*, it will be ordinary git-repo) and use git command